# SQL Query optimisation for PS

Tags: sql, prestashop, innodb

I am currently creating my webshop for my local parts store using prestashop 1.7.8.6

I developed scripts on myself and have successfully made the website work correctly.

But, with 2 millions rows of products including each 30 columns and multiple joins, i can't have a decent loading time on getProducts query.

Even with indexes and cache...

I use a simple query on prestashop product table and join id products from car filter table to match ps_product table.

I would like to know if it would be better to create tables for each vehicle using an id, and fill it with ps_product data, to use this table only instead of using multiple joins.

I'am using innoDB as engine.

Thanks

Comment: If you have 2 millions product rows for cars, then there is somethign wrong in your design. You need to look at product attributes and expand these to have variations on base products. And if you still need 2 million product rows, then PrestaShop may not be the right tool for your needs. And finally, seeking recommendations is off-topic here. See How to Ask helop topic.

Comment: I give you an example. If you sell shock absorbers, you can create a base product, then use attributes for front, rear, gas/oil based, brand, vehicle model-year. And if it is not fine-grained enough, then look at what is available as plugins. And if you cannot find what you need, then either develop it with attributes or look at other web-shop engine suites that better fits your needs out of the box. PrestaShop is kind of a low-end budget fit-all solution that may not be what you need. And if on budget constraints, then try to scale things down with less attributes to reduce complexity.

Comment: Show us one of the slow queries -- and the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables involved.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop does not have great performance with such a huge amount of data/products, as you have seen using native methods, so the best option is to strengthen your MySQL server.

Consider using one or more dedicated machines for SQL with replication),
by saving your data in external tables or store it to some distributed NoSQL system built to deal with large amount of data (like Elasticsearch or similar) so you can scale it easily and you can write your own code/module to retrieve what you need.